# How do I search the Usenet archives only in Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups, usenet

When I use the search function in Google Groups, the results contain not only Usenet posts, but also Google Groups posts. Is there a way to exclude Google Groups posts from the search results? I only want to search the Usenet archives through the Google Groups web interface.